# publicar aplicación windows form y descargarla desde mi página web

Tags: c#, publish

Estoy intentando implementar mi aplicación de escritorio desarrollada en `c# framework 4.5.2` en mi servidor web y al descargarla recibo el siguiente error:

```
URLDownloadToCacheFile falló con HRESULT '-2146697210' 
Error: Error al intentar descargar 'http://myWEB:8080/Download/DownloadApp/MyAppDesktop.application'.
```

He verificado como prerrequisitos el `framework .net 4.5.2` y el `instalador de windows 4.5` al instalar mi App

Esta es la primera vez que intento implementar una aplicación y se puede descargar como instalador desde mi sitio web.

Si alguien puede orientarme sobre lo que puede estar saliendo mal, se lo agradezco de antemano.

imagen adjunta del registro:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Consulte el documento de MSDN: Solución de errores específicos en implementaciones ClickOnce. Si un usuario ha configurado la opción de seguridad avanzada de Internet Explorer "Advertir si se cambia entre el modo seguro y no seguro" en el equipo de destino de implementación, y si la URL de configuración de la aplicación ClickOnce que se está instalando se redirige de un sitio no seguro a uno seguro ( o viceversa), la instalación fallará porque la advertencia de Internet Explorer la interrumpe. Para resolver esto, puede realizar una de las siguientes acciones: Desactive la opción de seguridad. Asegúrese de que la URL de configuración no se redirija de tal manera que cambie los modos de seguridad. Elimine la redirección por completo y apunte a la URL de configuración real.

Comment: lo acabo de solucionar, resulta que en el asistente de publicación se solicita la URL de descarga, y en los tutoriales como ejemplo especifican la URL de la página web de donde se accede la descarga, pero está mal, ahí hay que especificar la Ruta del directorio de donde se descarga la app.